# Pandas speedup when working with transposed numpy matrix

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance, numpy, transpose

I was trying to figure which is faster to standardize date between `numpy` and `pandas` and using the whole matrix/DataFrame or column by column and I've found this strange behavior showed in the code below

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def stand(df):
    res = pd.DataFrame()
    for col in df:
        res[col] = (df[col] - df[col].min()) / df[col].max()
    return res

matrix = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,174000,size=(1000000, 100)))
matrix.shape
(1000000, 100)


%timeit res = (matrix - matrix.min(axis=0))/ matrix.max(axis=0)
2.64 s ± 22.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit stand(matrix)
5.32 s ± 12.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

But when starting from a "flipped" numpy matrix and transposing it to create the DataFrame

```py
matrix = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,174000,size=(100, 1000000)).T)
matrix.shape
(1000000, 100)


%timeit res = (matrix - matrix.min(axis=0))/ matrix.max(axis=0)
2.37 s ± 18.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit stand(matrix)
1.2 s ± 8.06 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The execution of the standardization column by column get ~4 times faster.

This behavior remains also using `.values` or `numpy` operations as showed below:

```py
%timeit res = (matrix.values - matrix.min(axis=0).values)/ matrix.max(axis=0).values
2.58 s ± 417 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit stand(matrix)
5.26 s ± 42.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit res = np.divide(np.subtract(matrix.values, matrix.min(axis=0).values), matrix.max(axis=0).values)
2.17 s ± 7.32 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#Flipped matrix transpose
matrix = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,174000,size=(100, 1000000)).T)
matrix.shape
(1000000, 100)

%timeit res = (matrix.values - matrix.min(axis=0).values)/ matrix.max(axis=0).values
2.2 s ± 8.82 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit stand(matrix)
1.33 s ± 190 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit res = np.divide(np.subtract(matrix.values, matrix.min(axis=0).values), matrix.max(axis=0).values)
2.46 s ± 166 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Can someone explain why starting from a reversed matrix and then transposing it before to create the DataFrame changes the performance w.r.t. starting from a non-reversed matrix?

Comment: The transposed array has `order='F'`, column order.  That matches the Series orientation of a Dataframe.  Your `stand` function is iterating across columns, processing one column, or Series, at a time.